# My page is adding extra query string parameter without any reason

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, pageload

I have a page which is usually called with id parameter to get the details for specific object, something like:

http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/productdetails.aspx?Id=1982

On page_load this is the code I have:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Request.QueryString[0] != null)
                {

                    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                    tbl = hpl.getProductDetail(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0]));
                    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("ProductList.aspx");
                }
            }
```

And this is the error I'm getting http://prntscr.com/jd554l

also the URL adds extra parameter and it becomes http://www.mywebsite.com/admin/productdetails.aspx?Id=1982&Id=1982

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I think you posted the wrong code. Your snippet does not show how you are adding a querystring item to the url, only reading it. Also the error message is a result of the double querystring item, not the cause.

Comment: @VDWWD the link I'm clicking is https://prnt.sc/jd7ayd which as you can see is with one query string param. Thanks for your help

Comment: then something is happening between the click and the next page.